# Boot up multiple iOS simulators of same hardware and OS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

Is it possible to boot up multiple iOS simulators of the same hardware type (e.g. iPhone 7) and OS (e.g. iOS 10.3) on the same machine and under the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 9, it's not only possible, it's trivial.

[image]

Otherwise, you'd need to jump through some pretty forbidding hoops, like virtualizing the system.

Comment: Thanks, actually just installed Xcode 9 and figured it out. Pretty cool :)